# Pandas: Convert value with multiple ranges into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After some googling and without any good match, I'd like you to help me out with the following transformation. I've got some ranges in the values written in `{FROM-TO}` style:

```py
df_current = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': ['test{1-2}this{1-3}', 'or{2-3}'], 'B': ['yes', 'no']})

    A                   B
0   test{1-2}this{1-3}  yes
1   or{2-3}             no
```

For further processing, I'd like to create this:

```py
df_wish  = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({ \
    'A': [\
        'test1this1', 'test1this2', 'test1this3',\
        'test2this1', 'test2this2', 'test2this3', \
        'or2', 'or3'],
    'B': [ \
        'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', \
        'no', 'no']})

    A           B
0   test1this1  yes
1   test1this2  yes
2   test1this3  yes
3   test2this1  yes
4   test2this2  yes
5   test2this3  yes
6   or2         no
7   or3         no
```

Note that B is simply duplicated for the new rows.

Thanks,
René

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use:**

```
import re
from itertools import product

def mapper(s):
    lst = re.findall(r'(\w+)\{(\d+)-(\d+)\}', s)
    prd = [['{}{}'.format(*p) for p in product([w], range(int(m), int(n) + 1))] for w, m, n in lst]
    return list(map(''.join, product(*prd)))

df['A'] = df['A'].map(mapper)
df = df.explode('A').reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Details:**

STEP A: Define a `mapper` function which takes input as a string argument e.g `'test{1-2}this{1-3}'` and maps this string to generate all possible strings that can be obtained by multiplying ranges with corresponding words. The working of function `mapper` for the input string `'test{1-2}this{1-3}'` can be further explained as:

```
print(lst) # Use 're.findall' to parse all the words and their corresponding ranges
[('test', '1', '2'), ('this', '1', '3')]

print(prd) # Use 'itertools.product' to get all inner level products
[['test1', 'test2'], ['this1', 'this2', 'this3']]

# Again use 'itertools.product' to get all outer level products
['test1this1', 'test1this2', 'test1this3', 'test2this1', 'test2this2', 'test2this3']
```

STEP B: Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) on column `A` to map the function `mapper` on each value of column `A`.

```
# print(df)

                                                                          A    B
0  [test1this1, test1this2, test1this3, test2this1, test2this2, test2this3]  yes
1                                                                [or2, or3]   no
```

STEP C: Use [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) on column `A` to transform each list like value in column `A` to rows replicating index values.

```
# print(df)
            A    B
0  test1this1  yes
1  test1this2  yes
2  test1this3  yes
3  test2this1  yes
4  test2this2  yes
5  test2this3  yes
6         or2   no
7         or3   no
```